# How to make Html tags flip side in rtl mode?

Tags: html, css, right-to-left

I have a web need to convert to rtl. 
I added `dir="rtl"`  in html tag.

```
<div class="alert alert-info">BLAH BLAH <a class="url-help" target="_blank" href="some_url">LEARN_MORE</a></div>
```

[image]

Why the Learn More link is still on the right side in RTL mode?

Comment: Don't use `dir="rtl"` unless you have a language that is read from right to left.

Comment: @jsalonen The sole purpose is to support Arabic for our page

Comment: Great! Just double-checking nobody is mixing this up with visual layout.

Comment: @Zen did you actually test this with arabic text, and setting the `lang` to `ar` and `dir="rtl"` on the `html` tag?

Comment: @t.niese I don't know Arabic, so I use english to test. Will arabic make a difference?

Comment: @Zen afaik yes. If I remember correctly the browser determines the display order and the writing direction upon the `dir` settings, the `lang` and on the text that is written. I don't have the time to do some research to give a qualified answer, but having a short look at [MDN: unicode-bidi](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-bidi) seems that I recall right. You should do some research in this direction, before completely messing up your `css` and `html`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have to specify the direction on the `a` element itself:

```
<div class="alert alert-info">BLAH BLAH
    <a dir="rtl" class="url-help" target="_blank" href="some_url">LEARN_MORE</a>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mB4zy/1).

Comment: This is better than my answer, use this

Comment: Why is a tag different from other tags?

Comment: I see that the fiddle shows dir="rtl" on the body tag, not the HTML tag as the original question specified.  Not sure if that matters.

Comment: @andi I did this as the code given in the question doesn't show where the direction is added. It doesn't matter though, if the `div` element has the direction it still generates the same result.

Comment: The first sentence of the question specifies the html tag.  I'm also curious as to whether there is a way to do this without adding extra dir="rtl" markup.

Comment: @Zen I'm not entirely sure. The [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-dir-attribute) doesn't seem to specify the behaviour on `a` elements in this case.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I am wondering if there is a way to do it with least changes on my mark up. Without adding extra dir attr to tags, I have a global dir attr set to html tag already.

Comment: @Zen Perhaps you could use CSS? `html[dir="rtl"] a { float: left; }`

Comment: @jamesDonnelly I tried directional css for a tag, doesnt work either. Worst case, I will use css, adding dir attr to every a tag is not applicable for my case

Comment: @JamesDonnelly But float will pull the help link to the very left. That's not what I want.

Comment: @Zen I'm not able to help any further as I need to drive home now. Unfortunately I think setting the attribute is your best option, as you'd have to heavily work your CSS to cater for all situations (and this isn't something I'd be able to help with without knowing a lot about your website).

Answer (score 2):

You would have to change the order in your markup, or float each one to the right.

Floats would introduce all kinds of CSS issues, so it is ideal if you can just change the order in your markup

Comment: I want the page can be toggle between lrtl and rtl. Changing the order in markup is the last thing I want to do.